# Ejecutar accion todos los dias a la misma hora en C#

Tags: c#, consola, timer

estoy trabajando en una aplicación de Consola que debe realizar algunas acciones en horarios determinados del día (aclaro que no es un servicio porque necesito la ejecución de procesos)

El asunto es que debo iniciar una aplicación en un momento determinado y cerrarla en otro.

Buscando, encontre una [respuesta en S.O en Inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18611442/5213794) que hace algo similar a lo que busco pero con una única ejecución, intenté modificar un poco el snippet de la siguiente manera:

```
    private void SetUpTimer(TimeSpan alertTime, DateTime current, Action<TimeSpan> delg)
    {            

        TimeSpan timeToGo = alertTime - current.TimeOfDay;

        if (timeToGo < TimeSpan.Zero)
        { 
            return;//time already passed
        }
        this.timer = new System.Threading.Timer(x =>
        {
            delg(alertTime);
        }, null, timeToGo, Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
    }

    public void OpenProcess(TimeSpan alertTime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ejecutado {0}",DateTime.Now);            
        SetUpTimer(alertTime, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), OpenProcess);
    }
```

y luego lo llamo de la siguiente manera

```
SetUpTimer(new TimeSpan(13, 44, 00), DateTime.Now, OpenProcess);
```

La primera vuelta la hace de manera correcta, pero la segunda vez, la función OpenProcess() no se ejecuta

¿Dónde esta mi error?

Gracias!

Comment: Yo te recomendaría usar un tarea programada de windows para ejecutar tu programa

Comment: @Pikoh Muchas gracias por el consejo, encare el problema por este lado debido a que tengo que usar una Api (de la aplicación que necesito correr) y me pareció mas controlable hacerlo todo desde el mismo lugar, iniciar el programa, hacer las acciones con la api y matar el proceso, crees que es mejor hacer cada cosa por su lado?, muchas gracias por la respuesta también!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En tu código `timeToGo` marca el tiempo que falta para que vuelva a ejecutarse tu timer y se define como una resta de un `TimeStamp` (`alertTime`) de otro (`current.TimeOfDay`).

Que ocurre cuando llamas a `SetUpTimer(alertTime, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), OpenProcess);` desde el `OpenProcess`?

Que utilices `AddDays` es irrelevante, ya que para calcular el tiempo usas `TimeOfDay` que no tiene en cuenta la fecha, y además lo llamas a la misma hora en la que se supone debe saltar el tick del timer, con lo que en realidad `timeToGo` da un resultado negativo, y lógicamente no volverá a dispararse al día siguiente.

Yo ya te he dicho en un comentario que es mejor en mi opinión utilizar una tarea programada de windows para estos menesteres, pero te doy una solución si insistes por este camino.

La solución es usar fechas en lugar de TimeStamps para el cálculo del tiempo que falta para volver a disparar el tick del timer, algo asi:

```
private void SetUpTimer(Datetime alertTime, Action<TimeSpan> delg)
{            

    TimeSpan timeToGo = alertTime - DateTime.Now;
    ...
}
```

Para llamarlo la primera vez, asi (si es antes de la hora a la que lo programas):

```
DateTime fechaProxEjecución = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 13, 44, 0);
SetUpTimer(fechaProxEjecución,OpenProcess);
```

Y `OpenProcess` quedaría asi:

```
public void OpenProcess(TimeSpan alertTime)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ejecutado {0}",DateTime.Now);            
    DateTime fechaProxEjecución = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day+1, 13, 44, 0);
    SetUpTimer(fechaProxEjecución,OpenProcess);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Creo que la mejor manera de hacer esto es implementar el concepto de Workers. Debes hacer que tu aplicación de Consola ejecute la acción requerida al instante, sin revisar horarios ni fechas, y luego programar una tarea recurrente a través del sistema operativo.
En el caso de Microsoft Windows se puede usar Task Scheduler - Create a Basic Task - Declaras cada cuanto se va a ejecutar la tarea - Action = Start a program, buscas la aplicación de Consola y Listo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sin duda la mejor opción

Comment: Me encantó la opción que planteaste, voy a intentar encararlo por este camino, muchas gracias!