# Crear temporizador en C#

Tags: c#, timer

Estoy creando un programa en C# que me ayude a recordar cuando tomar mis medicinas. Para ello me pregunta si he tomado la pastilla y si es sí reinicial el programa 48 horas después.

De momento he creado un timer de 2 segundos para comprobar si funcioma, pero no consigo hacer pasar ese tiempo.

Espero me puedan ayudar, de momento mi código es el siguiente:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("¿Te has tomado la pastilla?");
        string x = Console.ReadLine();

        if (x == "Si")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Muy Bien");
            Timer timer = new Timer(172800000);//Creamos un temporizador de 48 horas

            Console.WriteLine("Perfect");
        }


    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Esta no es la mejor manera. Yo te recomendaría crear una Tarea Programada de Windows.

Comment: Lo sé y lo conozco, pero acabo de ponerme a aprender en C# y quería practicar.

Comment: Hace unas semanas tuve una problemática relativamente parecida y terminé solucionándolo como comenta @Pikoh con Tareas Programadas, si lo quieres hacer en C# de todos modos, te recomiendo leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/212961/77052), sino, mediante una tarea programada, [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/212964/77052)

Comment: muy costoso para un sistema mantener vivo este programa, recomiendo al igual que los demás, las tareas programadas.

Comment: Buenas  @DanielBolaMartínez, para que el Timer vaya ejecutandose primero tienes que iniciarlo con un `timer.Start();` y después controlas el temporizador con el evento `Tick` del timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar un [Timer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) en una aplicación de consola tenes que tener en cuenta principalmente dos cosas.

1. Debes suscribir al [Timer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.7.2) al evento [Elapsed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed?view=netframework-4.7.2) *(evento ejecutado cada vez que el timer cumpla su intervalo)*, para dentro de este realizar la acción que pretendes que se ejecute tras cierto tiempo
2. La aplicación debe quedar en un bucle infinito, para de esta manera, esperar a que se produzca el evento [Elapsed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed?view=netframework-4.7.2), de otra manera, la aplicación finalizaría su hilo de ejecución nunca produciéndose el evento.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de su aplicación.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   //Creo un timer con un intervalo de 2000 milisegundos.
   Timer t = new Timer(2000);
   //Suscribo el timer al evento elapsed. 
   t.Elapsed += EventoElapsed;
   //Lo inicio.
   t.Start();
   //Realizo un bucle infinito
   while (true);
}

/// <summary>
/// Evento producido en cada tick del Timer (cada 2000 milisegundos)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private static void EventoElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("¿Tomaste la pastilla?");
    //Manejas la respuesta a tu gusto
}
```

Sin embargo, como te han dicho en los comentarios, una mejor solución, sería la de usar Tareas Programadas, te dejo una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212953/ejecutar-accion-todos-los-dias-a-la-misma-hora-en-c/212964#212964), donde se explica como hacerlo

Answer (score 1):

Debes iniciar el Timer con Start y Y previamente asociar un evento Elapsed para cada fin de ciclo del timer. Además debes mantener el programa "vivo", por lo cual debes utilizar un bucle infinito para mantener en ejecución el programa.

para el siguiente programa, ejecuto el Elapsed cada 5 segundos.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Timer timer = new Timer(5000);
        timer.AutoReset = true;

        timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_elapsed);

        timer.Start();
        while (true) ;

    }

    private static void timer_elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("¿Te has tomado la pastilla?");
        string x = Console.ReadLine();


        if (x == "Si")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Muy Bien");
            Console.WriteLine("Perfect");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Deberias tomar la pastilla");
            Console.WriteLine("Es solo un consejo");
        }
    }




}
```