# ¿Poder ejecutar un servicio en una determinada hora del día en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows10, servicio, timer

Soy nuevo en la comunidad y necesito su ayuda, realicé un servicio donde ocupé un **System.Timers.Timer** donde la propiedad **Interval** la utilicé para que se ejecutara cada hora. Pero ahora requiero que se ejecute a cierta hora u horas del día.

Ejemplo: Que se ejecute todos los días a las 20:00 hrs. o que se ejecute los lunes y viernes a las 07:00 hrs.

Estuve investigando que existe una librería **Quartz** para el manejo de los tiempos, pero no encuentro algún ejemplo en concreto y cómo puedo implementarlo en mi servicio ya que todo mi código esta dentro del evento **Elapsed** que se crea con el **Timer**.

Dejo un fragmento de mi código para que me puedan ayudar:

```
namespace ServiceConnectionServerURL
{
    partial class ServiceConnection : ServiceBase
    {
        bool blBandera = false;
        public ServiceConnection()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            stLapso.Start();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            stLapso.Stop();
        }

        private void StLapso_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (blBandera) return;
            blBandera = true;
            string correo = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                //EventLog.WriteEntry("Se inicio Prueba de Conexión" + DateTime.Now.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Information);
                var ips = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ipConnection"].Split('|');
                foreach (var ip in ips)
                {
                    correo += $"\n {ValidarPing(ip)}";
                }

                string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["urlConnection"].ToString();
                correo += $"\n {ValidadURL(url)}";

                string error = EnvioCorreo(correo);
                if (error.Contains("Error"))
                {
                    EventLog.WriteEntry($"Service Connection Server URL \n{correo}\n\n {error}", EventLogEntryType.Error);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
            blBandera = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Y una tarea programada en Windows?

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Ejecutar accion todos los dias a la misma hora en C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/212953/ejecutar-accion-todos-los-dias-a-la-misma-hora-en-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas creando un servicio de windows la libreria que mencionas aplicaria muy bien, agregas la instancia usando nuget

[Quartz nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Quartz/)

para crear `task` programadas para ejecutar ante un `scheduler`

[Quartz.NET Quick Start Guide](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/quick-start.html)

puedes indicar un `cron trigger`

[Lesson 6: CronTrigger](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html)

```
trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
      .WithIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
      .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(10, 42))
      .ForJob(myJobKey)
      .Build();
```

Comment: Hola Leandro,
Soy nuevo en esto, donde pondría el código? Ya que quitaría el Timer y no tendría el evento StLapso_Elapsed ! Hay es donde ya no se como hacerle para mandar a llamar el nuevo evento y como crearlo. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: la definicion del job deberias hacerlo en el start del servicio, no hay evento sino que defines el job, leiste la documentacion de los links? alli veras que se crea una clase que hereda de `IJob` esa es la que se configura en la task que se aplica el scheduler